# How to get all possible values of a pickerWheels on iOS UITest?

Tags: ios, uipickerview, xcode-ui-testing

I have a UIPickerView on my app, with a list of values, we can use Colors. The picker has only one wheel, and I manage to select the value by using this code:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.launch()
app.pickerWheels.element.adjustToPickerWheelValue("Yellow")
```

But what I want to do is to get all the possible values of this wheel in an Array, so I can use the array values to select in the picker.

Another good solution would be to make the selection by index instead of by key, but I could not find ways of doing that. Someone?

Comment: This may not be the best of solution but what I did was pass some junk value  to adjustToPickerWheelValue("Garbage"), with this the test will fail and console prints error -  UI Testing Failure - Requested adjust to value 'Garbage' which is not one of the possible values Yellow, Red, etc for the picker wheel.
With these values you can create a static array in your test and use those values in your tests.

Comment: @Sandy thanks.. but I would like something more clean.. but seems it is not possible, so unfortunatelyI will need to stick with the label then.

Comment: If the purpose is to ask the app itself what the values are then (IMHO) this is the wrong approach. Your test should have an idea of what the values are (from requirements or from the test implementation itself if contingent) and should test that they are there. The `adjust(toPickerWheelValue:)` method fails the test if the value is not present.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this on another question as well.  You could get the number of values in the picker as x, then call this function x number of times.  And as the value updates the cell the picker is associated with you can grab the value from there to add it to your array.

Let me know if you have some questions...

Workaround:

```
let pickerWheel = XCUIApplication().pickers.pickerWheels.element
let appWindowHeight = XCUIApplication().windows.elementBoundByIndex(0).frame.height
let pickerWheelCellHeight = GFloat(44)
    func advancePickerWheelOneValue() -> Self {
         let topScrollPoint = Double(pickerWheel.frame.midY/appWindowHeight)
         let bottomScrollPoint = Double((pickerWheel.frame.midY + pickerWheelCellHeight)/appWindowHeight)
         let topScreenPoint = XCUIApplication().windows.elementBoundByIndex(0).coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: topScrollPoint))
         let bottomScreenPoint = XCUIApplication().windows.elementBoundByIndex(0).coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: bottomScrollPoint))
         bottomScreenPoint.pressForDuration(0, thenDragToCoordinate: topScreenPoint)
         return self
    }
```

You may need to adjust the dx value depending on where the picker is.

```
.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVector(dx: 0.5,
```

But 0.5 works if the picker occupies the width of the screen.

With this method you an move the picker on value at a time. Call it multiple times and you get to the value you want.

Its not ideal but it can help if you want to check certain indexes. Hopefully you would have to use it on a picker with hundreds of values ;)

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I needed it for my snapshot UI tests where I couldn´t just select a value by string in my picker wheel because of different locales.
But I needed to make some adjustments to make it work.
1) The dragging was not working for me, it always scrolled too far. I ended up just using a simple tap to "bottomScrollPoint" because the current item should always be in the middle anyways and therefore a tap on the item below the middle selects the next.
2) You dont have to hardcode the dx value. You can use the same calculation with the app window width as for the dy value