# UIPickerView and UI Unit Test: How to get values of UIPickerWheel?

Tags: swift, uipickerview, xcode-ui-testing

Recently I had a bad headache (and I'm still struggling) to find out how to retrieve all values inside an UIPickerWheel. For me should be enough to move at particular row of the wheel, but I can't! So frustrating! I tried to scroll row by row to retrieve all values (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39300344/821407) but it's so slow! Any clue?

NB: I can't use adjustToPickerWheelValue because my root problem is that I don't know the value since they are dynamic and I would like to avoid launchArguments/launchEnvironment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably not the answer you were hoping for but it is not possible to get the title of all rows in a `UIPickerView` in a UITest.

As you know when running a UITest you can only access your app's UI elements via the `XCUIElement` class. That class has a `value` property that gives you some information about the UI element you access. When accessing a `UIPickerView` the `value` gives you the title of the currently selected row. But only of the selected row. You can access the picker's row elements, but unfortunately the `value` property for the row elements is always empty. So, no luck here. All you the info you can get is the number of rows of your picker.

This is not really surprising though. Even if you had access to the `UIPickerView`, you could not access the titles of all rows directly. `UIPickerView` does not know about the titles that it displays. It is the job of the `UIPickerViewDataSource` to provide the titles.

So, unfortunately, if you need to know all the row titles of your `UIPickerView` in a UITest, you really have to select each value one by one via your app's user interface.

But it does not have to be as complicated as in the answer you linked. Instead of simulating a scroll you can simply tap on the next row to select it (should be slightly faster):

```
let pickerView = app.pickerWheels.element
let numRows = pickerView.children(matching: .any).count
var values: [String] = [pickerView.value as! String]

for _ in 0..<numRows {
    pickerView.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.55)).tap()
    values.append(pickerView.value as! String)
}
```

In your question you do not really describe what you are trying to test. But if you want to test if the picker has the correct row titles maybe a UnitTest would be a more practical approach?

Comment: thanks for your answer and I've really appreciated. I explain what I want to test: the UIPickerView is on a Search Form and I have to tap on it, select a random value and perform a search and then do some assertions. The problem is that the values in picker view are dynamic, so I don't know the values in advance. I remember that with Automation, the old tool in Instrument, you can access to a particular row by index. Anyway I will accept your answer because is the one I did, but it's still slow. I hope they will improve and I can adjust the values by Index